# Passing data to a previous screen

Tags: flutter, state

Firstly, if you pop a screen off, does it mean all initializations have been destroyed?

I initialized a few variables to a previous screen, was hoping to see the changes when I go back to the screen but I don't see the changes

Is it possible to pass a few data to a previous screen without moving to that screen? if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You could do it in some variety of ways.

A simple way could be like that:

Having a private variable at the beginning of the method scope in a StatefulWidget

```
String _fileAvatarUpload = '';
```

Then, you would have your widget tree being displayed and a Widget you want to return a value to the tree:

```
   Center(
          child: ImagePickerSource(
            isRunningWeb: kIsWeb,
            image: _peopleModel.imageAvatar,
            callback: callbackAvatar,
            isAvatar: true,
            imageQuality: 35,
          ),
        ),
```

In the callback method, you could use SetState to set the new value variable:

```
callbackAvatar(file, bytes) {
    setState(() {
      _fileAvatarUpload = file;
      _bytesImgWeb = bytes;
    });
  }
```